# Is There any way to get all mime type by the resourceType of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mime-types

There is many type of resourceType in chrome api,
for ex:Document, Stylesheet, Image, Media, Font, Script, TextTrack, XHR, Fetch, EventSource, WebSocket, Manifest, Other.

Now i want to know resourceType include which mime type.
i try to division it by myself but there are too many mimeType,so is there any way to get it by code?
for ex:  document→text/html...
         xhr→application/json...
         Image->image/png,image/jepg...
         font-> application/font-woff...

thank you very much!!!

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml and some are not recognized by IANA...

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,"iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml", i know this website, that's just mime-types i want to division,  i just want to division those mime types group by [Document, Stylesheet, Image, Media, Font, Script, TextTrack, XHR, Fetch, EventSource, WebSocket, Manifest, Other.]

Answer (score 5):

In the search to an answer to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083776/how-is-defined-resourcetype-value-provided-by-the-devtool-protocol), I found the source code that handle that in the WebKit source code used by Chromium.

Not only the `mimeType` can be used to determine the `resourceType` but also the extension (from the url).

**Document**

- `mimeType`: 'text/html'

**Stylesheet**

- `mimeType`: 'text/css'
- extension: css, xsl

**Image**

- `mimeType` starting with: 'image/'
- extension: jpeg, jpg, svg, gif, png, ico, tiff, tif, bmp

**Media**

- extension: webp

**Font**

- `mimeType` having 'font' in it
- extension: ttf, otf, ttc, woff

**Script**

- `mimeType` starting with 'text/' (but not 'text/html' nor 'text/css') or having 'script' or 'application' in it
- extension: js

**TextTrack**, **XHR**, **Fetch**, **EventSource**, **WebSocket** and **Manifest** are handle by custom logic by the engine during the processing of the given resource.

**Other** is the default for anything not falling in the previous categories.

---

Source code is availlable here: [./third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/common/ResourceType.js](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/64.0.3261.1/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/common/ResourceType.js).