# Node Puppeteer, page.on( "request" ) throw a "Request is already handled!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using [`puppeteer-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra) and node.js to iterate accross multiple urls.

I'm trying to intercept some resourceType to load upon each iteration, and getting the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\Project> node temp.js
-- running
C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\assert.js:26
        throw new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Request is already handled!
    at Object.exports.assert (C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\assert.js:26:15)
    at HTTPRequest.continue (C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\HTTPRequest.js:217:21)
    at PuppeteerBlocker.onRequest (C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\@cliqz\adblocker-puppeteer\dist\cjs\adblocker.js:225:33)
    at BlockingContext.onRequest (C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\@cliqz\adblocker-puppeteer\dist\cjs\adblocker.js:64:47)
    at C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\vendor\mitt\src\index.js:51:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\vendor\mitt\src\index.js:51:43)
    at Page.emit (C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\EventEmitter.js:72:22)
    at C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:143:100
    at C:\Users\someuser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\vendor\mitt\src\index.js:51:62
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the request would be already handled as the actual request `page.goto` is done while in the `for` loop. Would anyone one have any hints?

Here is the full project

```
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer-extra' );

const StealthPlugin = require( 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth' );
puppeteer.use( StealthPlugin() );

const AdblockerPlugin = require( 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker' );
puppeteer.use( AdblockerPlugin( { blockTrackers: true } ) );

puppeteer.launch( { headless: true } ).then( async browser => {

    console.log( '--\xa0running' );

    console.time( '--\xa0process' );

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setRequestInterception( true );
    
    page.on( 'request', ( request ) => {
        if ( [ 'image', 'stylesheet', 'font', 'script' ].indexOf( request.resourceType() ) ) {
            request.abort();
        } else {
            request.continue();
        };
    } );

    for ( var i = 1; i <= 20; i++ ) {

        console.time( '--\xa0iteration\xa0' + i ); // ... timer start 
    
        await page.goto( 'https://www.someurl.it/shop/s%2D' + i, { waitUntil: 'load' } );
    
        const title = await page.title();
    
        console.log( title.includes( '404' ) ? false : title );
    
        console.timeEnd( '--\xa0iteration\xa0' + i ); // ... timer end 
    
    };

    await browser.close();

    console.timeEnd( '--\xa0process' );
  
    console.log( '--\xa0ending' );

} );
```

Comment: What if you add `await` before the `request.abort();` and `request.continue();` (as both methods return promises)?

Comment: See also https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5334

Comment: Sadly await isn't doing the trick. The Github thread is interesting tho not solving the issue. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ressources interception must be made against each new pages.

Here is the full list of ressources you can intercept: `stylesheet`, `image`, `media`, `font`, `script`, `texttrack`, `xhr`, `fetch`, `eventsource`, `websocket`, `manifest`, `other`.

> **Note:**
> Most of the time, intercepting ALL resources might negatively impact your scraper.

I would advise to ONLY intercept `image`, `media` and `font`. (In some cases intercepting `stylesheet` might impact puppeteer click action).

#### Example

```js
/**
 * Puppeteer, Headless Chrome Node.js API
 * 
 * @link https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
 * 
 * @package npm install puppeteer
 */
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

const brewery = async ( page ) => {

    await page.setRequestInterception( true );

    page.on( 'request', r => {

        /**
         * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166637/3645650
         */
        if ( [
            //'stylesheet', 
            'image', 
            'media', 
            'font',
        ].indexOf( r.resourceType() ) !== -1 ) {

            r.abort();

        } else {

            r.continue();

        };

    } );

};

( async () => {

    // ... start
    let start = new Date();
    console.log( '--\xa0process:\xa0start' );

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { 
        headless: true 
    } );

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await brewery( page );

    await page.goto( 'https://github.com/login' );
    await page.screenshot( { path: Date.now() + '.png' } );
    console.log( '--\xa0process:\xa0screenshot' );

    // ... end
    await browser.close().then( () => {
        var end = ( new Date() - start ) / 1000;
        console.log( '--\xa0process:\xa0end,\xa0runtime\xa0' + end + '\xa0seconds' );
    } );  

} ) ()
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding a return statement solved the issue on my end.

```
page.on( 'request', ( request ) => {
        if ([ 'image', 'stylesheet', 'font', 'script' ].indexOf( request.resourceType() ) !== -1 ) {
           return request.abort();
        }
        request.continue();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
page.on("request", (request) => {
  const requestUrl = request.url();
  if (!request.isInterceptResolutionHandled())
    if (
      blockResourceType.includes(request.resourceType()) ||
      blockResourceName.some((resource) => requestUrl.includes(resource))
    ) {
      request.abort();
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
});
```

You can try this to avoid this error message